# Nested for-loops with different function calls

Tags: c#, for-loop

I am currently revising for finals. Doing some exam prep and came across this particular past question which I am finding it hard to grasp.

The question asks to write the output from the following code:

```
    private static Dictionary<int, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    private static int value = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    Test0(); //Test0 = 12
                    Console.WriteLine("Test0 = " + i.ToString()); 
                }


                else if (i == 1)
                {
                    Test1(i);
                    Console.WriteLine("Test1 = " + i.ToString());           
                }
                else if (i == 2 && i % 2 == 0) 
                {
                    Test2(ref i); //i=2
                    Console.WriteLine("Test2 = " + i.ToString());
                }

                else if (i == 2)
                {
                    Test1(i); //i=3
                    Console.WriteLine("Test1 = " + i.ToString());                     
                }

                else if (i == 3)
                {
                    Test3(ref i);
                }

                else if (i == 4)
                {
                    string str;
                    str = Test4(i);
                    Console.WriteLine("Test4 = " + (int.Parse(str) + i));                        
                }

                else if (i == 5)
                {
                    Test5(i);
                    Test5(i - 2);
                }

                else if (i == 6)
                {
                    Test6(ref i);
                    Console.WriteLine("Added item to dictionary.");
                }

                else if (myDictionary[i] == "six")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Item 6 is in the dictionary.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Entered else clause");
                    int zero = 0;
                    int result = i / zero;
                    Console.WriteLine("Result is " + result.ToString());
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("End of loop reached");

        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Catch clause entered");
        }

        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Finally clause entered");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Finished");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    private static void Test0()
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 2; j++)
            {
                result += i;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Test0 = " + result.ToString());
    }
    private static void Test1(int i)
    {
        i = 3;
    }
    private static void Test2(ref int i)
    {
        i = 2;
    }
    private static void Test3(ref int i)
    {
        i = Convert.ToInt32(i + "1") % 9;
    }
    private static string Test4(int i)
    {
        string str;
        str = i.ToString() + i.ToString();
        return str;
    }
    private static void Test5(int i)
    {
        Program.value -= i; //value = 0
        Console.WriteLine("Test5 = " + Program.value.ToString());
    }
    private static void Test6(ref int i)
    {
        myDictionary.Add(i, "six");
        Console.WriteLine("Test6 = " + myDictionary[i]);

    }


}
```

The answer I had was this:

```
Test0 = 12
Test0 = 0
Test1 = 3
Test2 = 2
Test1 = 3
Test5 = -5
Test5 = -3
Test6 = six
Added item to dictionary
End of loop reached
Catch clause entered
Finally clause entered
Finished
```

Which is obviously wrong. The correct answer is:

```
Test0 = 12
Test0 = 0
Test1 = 1
Test2 = 2
Test5 = -5
Test5 = -8
Test6 = six
Added item to dictionary.
Catch clause entered
Finally clause entered
Finished
```

Anyone feeling like a challnege...? Explanation would be much appreciated. It is a long code... approximate time given for this question in exam was around 15 - 20 minutes.

Thanks

Comment: you write what this code is suppose to do and what it is doing wrong ?

Comment: Its not really suppose to 'do' something. It was a question from a past exam and I have been struggling with getting the correct ansewer as I provided. Some explanation on method call and parameters being called would be helpful...

Comment: so you are saying, there was this program written in question paper and that's it? Or you have to make these test methods by yourself to meet the expected output ?

Comment: There was this program written in question paper and that is it.

Comment: if you were studying in university where i studied, you might have got a question paper with a code and proper description regarding what to do to this code.

Comment: Sorry perhaps my question wasn't clear. The question from the exam states to "write the output" from the above code. Will amend it accordingly, cheers

Comment: So it is dry running question. you are not suppose to use computer or code editor for this question.

Comment: No. It was on a piece of paper if thats what you mean. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, you go each and every line of code one by one - from start to end. calculate arithmetic, keep pre and post increment operation in mind, note that method calling are in stack format and Note every output (console writing)

Comment: Hints: the value of `i` in your loop does not get modified by the method calls (even though they  set `i=`) *unless* those methods are called using `MethodName(ref i)`. The ones that set `program.value` are seen everywhere because that field is static. `i==4` is skipped completely and `i==2` is never hit because `i==2 && i%2==0` will match first

Comment: Also, when an exception is thrown (ie divide by zero) the very next thing to happen will be the `catch` clause (if a matching catch exists) or the program will crash (after the finally is run) if no catch exists/matches the type of exception. The next line of code will not happen. Go directly to catch, do not execute next statement, do not collect $200.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a trace where i = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 (crash)

> When `i = 0`

the code calls the `Test0()` method. This method simply loops through some “local” variables and outputs a result. “Test0 = 12” Note: the `i` variable is “local” and is not the same `i` variable used in the main `for` loop counter.

```
if (i == 0) {
  Test0(); //Test0 = 12
  Console.WriteLine("Test0 = " + i.ToString());
} else...   

private static void Test0() {
  int result = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 2; j++) {
      result += i;
    }
  }
  Console.WriteLine("Test0 = " + result.ToString());
}
```

Once the code returns from `Test0()`… Output…

```
Test0 = 12
```

Note: the “local” `i` variable from `Test0` has gone out of scope and the `i` counter variable in the `for` loop is output…

```
Test0 = 12
Test0 = 0
```

> When i = 1

The code continues… loops back up to the `for` loop, increments `i = 1`.  Enters the code…

```
if (i == 1) {
  Test1(i);
  Console.WriteLine("Test1 = " + i.ToString());
} else...

private static void Test1(int i) {
  i = 3;
}
```

When `i = 1` the code calls the `Test1(i)` method. This method is taking an `int` variable as a parameter. When the code enters the `Test1(int i)` method… a “new LOCAL” variable `i` is created. `i`’s  initial value is 1 which was passed in. The code simply sets “local” `i` variable to three (3) then returns.

Once the code returns from `Test1(i)` the `i` variable created in the method is no longer in scope and the next line of code will output the `i` variable that is used in the `for` loop counter, which is still one (1). Output…

```
Test0 = 12
Test0 = 0
Test1 = 1
```

> When i = 2

The code continues… branches back up to the `for` loop, increments `i = 2`.  Enters the code…

```
if (i == 2 && i % 2 == 0) {
  Test2(ref i); //i=2
  Console.WriteLine("Test2 = " + i.ToString());
} else...

private static void Test2(ref int i) {
  i = 2;
}
```

A side note is below. 
Here the variable is passed in by `ref` (reference). Currently the `for` counter variable `i` is 2. When the code enters the `Test2(ref int i)` method it does NOT create its own “local” copy. The counter variable `i` used in the main program is “exposed” to this method and it “can” change it… as the code obligingly does with the next line of code: `i = 2;` This is fortunate that the current value of `i` IS already 2. Changing `i` in this fashion is highly discouraged and I would consider it risky at best crashing at worst.

Continuing… `i` is still 2 after returning from `Test2(ref i)` Output…

```
Test0 = 12
Test0 = 0
Test1 = 1
Test2 = 2
```

> When i = 3

The code continues… branches back up to the `for` loop, increments `i = 3`.  Enters the code…

```
if (i == 3) {
  Test3(ref i);
} else...

private static void Test3(ref int i) {
  i = Convert.ToInt32(i + "1") % 9;
}
```

When `i = 3` the code calls the `Test3(ref i)` method. Here, it appears this method is trying to “change” the `i` counter variable in the main loop. To break it down when we know `i = 3`…

```
i = Convert.ToInt32(i + "1") % 9;
```

Becomes

```
i = Convert.ToInt32(“31”) % 9;
```

This will return four (4) since 31 mod 9 = 4. This is the value the main `for` loops counter variable `i` is set to. This means the code will skip when `i=4` since it is getting set to 4 here… when the code branches back up to the `for` loop… it is going to set `i` to 5. In addition, there is NO output when `i = 3`… to sum up since there was no new output…It is the same as the previous iteration of the loop.

```
Test0 = 12
Test0 = 0
Test1 = 1
Test2 = 2
```

> When i = 5

The code continues… branches back up to the `for` loop, remember the previous call to `Test3(ref i)` changed `i` to four (4), therefore the `if` construct increments `i` to `i = 5`.  Enters the code…

```
if (i == 5) {
  Test5(i);
  Test5(i - 2);
} else...


private static void Test5(int i) {
  Program.value -= i; //value = 0
  Console.WriteLine("Test5 = " + Program.value.ToString());
}
```

When `i = 5` the code calls the `Test5(i)` method twice. The `Test5(int i)` method takes one `int` parameter `i`, then subtracts the value of `i` from a global variable `value`. At this stage we “know” `value=0`, therefore `value` is set to -5. Then outputs `value`… Output…

```
Test0 = 12
Test0 = 0
Test1 = 1
Test2 = 2
Test5 = -5
```

`Test5(i);` returns and a second call is made with `Test5(i - 2);`…

To keep track, `i = 5` AND `value = -5`… therefore the above call using `i-2` could be re-written as…

`Test5(3);`

Here inside Test5, `i` = 3, the code subtracts 3 from `value` `value = -8`, then outputs…

```
Test0 = 12
Test0 = 0
Test1 = 1
Test2 = 2
Test5 = -5
Test5 = -8
```

> When i = 6

The code continues… branches back up to the `for` loop, increments `i` to `i = 6`.  Enters the code…

```
if (i == 6) {
  Test6(ref i);
  Console.WriteLine("Added item to dictionary.");
} else...

private static void Test6(ref int i) {
  myDictionary.Add(i, "six");
  Console.WriteLine("Test6 = " + myDictionary[i]);
}
```

`Test6(ref int i)` method adds a value to a global dictionary `myDictionary` and outputs from the dictionary. Output….

```
Test0 = 12
Test0 = 0
Test1 = 1
Test2 = 2
Test5 = -5
Test5 = -8
Test6 = six
```

Once the code returns from `Test6(ref int i)`, a line is output…

```
Test0 = 12
Test0 = 0
Test1 = 1
Test2 = 2
Test5 = -5
Test5 = -8
Test6 = six
Added item to dictionary.
```

> When i = 7

The code continues… branches back up to the `for` loop, increments `i` to `i = 7`.  Enters the code…

```
if (myDictionary[i] == "six") {
  Console.WriteLine("Item 6 is in the dictionary.");
}
else {
  Console.WriteLine("Entered else clause");
  int zero = 0;
  int result = i / zero;
  Console.WriteLine("Result is " + result.ToString());
}
```

The code below is throwing the exception.

```
myDictionary[i] == "six"
```

Since `i = 7`, `myDictionary[i]` is going to fail and throw a “key” not present in dictionary exception, and this makes sense since we know there is only one item in the dictionary and it is 6. Therefore, the exception is being caught and the display updates…

```
Test0 = 12
Test0 = 0
Test1 = 1
Test2 = 2
Test5 = -5
Test5 = -8
Test6 = six
Added item to dictionary.
Catch clause entered
```

The `finally` clause of the try statement is executed….

```
Test0 = 12
Test0 = 0
Test1 = 1
Test2 = 2
Test5 = -5
Test5 = -8
Test6 = six
Added item to dictionary.
Catch clause entered
Finally clause entered
```

Finally the last line is output and code exits. Output…

```
Test0 = 12
Test0 = 0
Test1 = 1
Test2 = 2
Test5 = -5
Test5 = -8
Test6 = six
Added item to dictionary.
Catch clause entered
Finally clause entered
Finished
```

Below, the compound `if` condition (and the one after) doesn’t make a lot of sense. If `i` does NOT equal two (2) then (due to short-circuit) the second part of the “and” condition will never be evaluated. Therefore, the only time `i % 2 == 0` will be evaluated is when `i=2`??? I am confident modulo(2,2) will always return 0. The point here is the second condition is never evaluated unless `i = 2` which will always be true, therefore this `if` can be rewritten as `if (i == 2)`. This is why the “second” `if (i == 2)` statement in the “else” portion of this `if (i == 2)` statement will NEVER be executed.

```
else if (i == 2 && i % 2 == 0) {
  Test2(ref i); //i=2
  Console.WriteLine("Test2 = " + i.ToString());
}
else if (i == 2)
  {… never get here….
```

To help, I recommend you look closer at a “red flag” in the code. Passing by ref is not a big problem, however, passing an “index” of a loop by ref and changing its value is a huge red flag waving. Tracing the code just got more complicated. It is something you need to understand fully hence the test. The test is doing something (changing a loop index) that you would rarely see in any environment. Therefore, extra care is needed when tracing code that does this.